# Property mocking not returning the Mock.return_value set

Tags: python-3.x, rest, mocking, python-unittest

In a test file, I mock a property `property` of a class `MyClass` defined in `path.to.my.module` like this:

```
# test file
import unittest
from app.module import run_service
class TestMyService(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      self.service_url = ...
      self.query = ...
      self.headers = ....
   def test_my_service(self):
     proc = Process(target=run_service)
     proc.start()
     with patch("path.to.my.module.MyClass.property", new_callable=PropertyMock) as attr:
        attr.return_value = "expected_value"
        res = requests.get(self.service_url, self.query, headers=self.headers)
     self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
     proc.join()
```

In real execution, `property` downloads something from an external service X. The GET of the service imports `MyClass`, instanciates it, and calls a function `prs` defined in a third module which has an argument of type `MyClass`. `prs` calls the property `property` of its argument.

When I run the test file above, the traceback travels up to where `prs` calls `MyClass.property` and tries to actually perform the download. I was expecting `MyClass.property` to return instead `"expected_value"`. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I would guess that you mock the wrong module - this depends on how `MyClass` is imported where it is used. Check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using "from module import smthg" in all scripts

Comment: In this case you have to patch `path_to_using_module.MyClass.property`.